# The function is a norm on $X$

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Show that if $(X, \langle, \rangle)$ is a space with inner product then the function $x \mapsto ||x||:= \langle x, x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a norm on $X$.

I have tried the following:

From the fact that $(X, \langle, \rangle)$ is a space with inner product we have the following properties:

- $\langle x, x \rangle \geq 0, \forall x \in X$ and $\langle x,x \rangle=0$ iff $x=0$.
- $\langle x,y \rangle= \langle y,x \rangle$
- $\langle \lambda x+ \mu y ,z \rangle= \lambda \langle x,z \rangle + \mu \langle y,z \rangle$

We want to show the following properties:

- $||x|| \geq 0$
- $||x||=0$ iff $x=0$
- $||\lambda x||=|\lambda| ||x||$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in X$
- $||x+y|| \leq ||x||+||y||$

$\langle x,x \rangle \geq 0 \Rightarrow \langle x, x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} \geq 0$ so the first property is satisfied.

$\langle x,x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0 \Rightarrow \langle x, x \rangle =0 \Rightarrow x=0$.

If $x=0$ then $\langle x,x \rangle=0 \Rightarrow \langle x,x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$.

Thus the second property is satisfied.

$||\lambda x||=\langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\lambda \langle  x, \lambda x \rangle)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\lambda^2 \langle  x,  x \rangle)^{\frac{1}{2}}=|\lambda| \langle x,x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Therefore, the third property is satisfied.

Is everything right so far? Or could I improve something?

$||x+y||= \langle x+y,x+y \rangle ^{\frac{1}{2}}= ( \langle x,x+y \rangle + \langle y,x+y \rangle)^{\frac{1}{2}}=( \langle x,x \rangle +2 \langle x,y \rangle+ \langle y,y \rangle)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Is it right so far? How could we show that the latter is $\leq \langle x,x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}+ \langle y,y \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$ ?

**EDIT**:If we us Cauchy-Schwarz in order to show the last property then would we get the following?

$$||x+y||= \langle x+y, x+y \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \langle x+y, x+y \rangle \cdot \langle x+y, x+y \rangle=||x||^2+ 2\langle x,y \rangle +||y||^2$$

Is it right so far? But if so, then wouldn't we have to show that $\langle x,y \rangle=0$, in this case?

Comment: All looks OK so far, except that in your proof of the $\textit{third}$ property, there is a $y$ where there shouldn't be.

Comment: Use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof).

Comment: You are correct just now( except a typo in the proof of the property 3).
The property 4 is the most difficult to prove. It is a consequrnce of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CauchySchwarz_inequality

Comment: Yes, I have also thought to use Cauchy-Schwarz. Then would we get the following?

$$||x+y||= \langle x+y, x+y \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \langle x+y, x+y \rangle \cdot \langle x+y, x+y \rangle=||x||^2+ 2\langle x,y \rangle +||y||^2$$

Is it right so far? But if so, then wouldn't we have to show that $\langle x,y \rangle=0$, in this case?

Comment: The property is $$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + 2 \langle x,y \rangle +\|y\|^2 \leq_{C.S}  \|x\|^2 + 2 \| x\| \|y\|  +\|y\|^2 = ( \|x\| + \|y\| )^2$$ Now take the square root of this inequality to get the result